# How to hide the checkout scm step output in console output of Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, github, devops

My first stage in Jenkinsfile(scripted pipeline) is checkout scm, which gives a brief description about the GitHub checkouts and all revision related things **which I don't want to display in Jenkins console output**.

Is it possible to hide this in console output of Jenkins.
following console output is from Jenkins for checkout scm step, which I want to hide

```
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository https://github.com/forpi/cherry-pik.git
 > git init /home/ubuntu/.jenkins/workspace/Dummy-project # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/forpi/cherry-pik.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/forpi/cherry-pik.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/forpi/cherry-pik.git # timeout=10
 > git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/forpi/cherry-pik.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/forpi/cherry-pik.git
 > git fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/forpi/cherry-pik.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision b80c4d6b655429d7f84347b4192461cc3d68283e (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f b80c4d6b69c429d7f84347b4192461cc3d68283e
 > git branch -a -v --no-abbrev # timeout=10
 > git checkout -b master b80c4d6b655429d7f84347b4192461cc3d68283e
Commit message: "lets try this again"
```

Comment: Is there any solution for this question? I'm struggling with thousands of git lines in console output whenever i use GitSCM.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout scm has option to provide arguments like this and there is a quietoperation   mode availabe

```
checkout([$class: 'SubversionSCM', 
        additionalCredentials: [], 
       locations: [[cancelProcessOnExternalsFail: true, 
        credentialsId: '234243-45654-234randomstuff', 
        depthOption: 'infinity', 
        ignoreExternalsOption: true, 
        local: '.', 
        remote: 'https://starkindustries/ironman/superGlueForThanosFingers/repo']],
        **quietOperation: true,** 
        workspaceUpdater: [$class: 'UpdateUpdater']])
```

You can also try this

```
checkout scm &> /dev/null
```

This will suppress stdout and stderr, unless the git command fails

or

If you want to checkout using git

```
git checkout origin master --quiet
git checkout origin master --q
```

Which is an available option in git.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: While the question text references git specifically, I'm looking for an answer that satisfies the title, i.e. can apply to any SCM

Comment: @AdamSmith the first two option will work for any SCM checkout SCM is a Jenkins options... Only the last one is specific to git

Comment: I'm getting error like below

checkout scm &> /dev/null
                    ^

1 error

 at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addFatalError(ErrorCollector.java:150)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:120)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:132)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.addError(SourceUnit.java:350)
Finished: FAILURE

Comment: @rohitthomas , when I tried to use this command in Jenkinsfile, I'm getting this WorkflowScript: 3: expecting '}', found 'scm' @ line 3, column 14.
       checkout scm &> /dev/null

Comment: any way to do this in a freestyle job?

Comment: Checkout scm is a pipeline feature... @senorsmile what do you want to do exactly ?

Answer (score -1):

Try this handy plugin:
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Collapsing+Console+Sections+Plugin

It may not be super neat but, it can get the work done.

Comment: Thank You @Curious, could you please help me how to configure this plugin for Git, I have tried all the possible ways that I can