# Hide GitSCM output from console / Jenkins

Tags: git, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Another entry with the same question exists here:
[How to hide the checkout scm step output in console output of Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52107661/how-to-hide-the-checkout-scm-step-output-in-console-output-of-jenkins)
Since it's not active, i m raising a different question.

I'm struggling with thousands of git output lines, making console load impossible.

> 06:08:18   > git submodule init # timeout=10 06:08:18
> git submodule sync # timeout=10 06:08:18   > git config --get
> remote.origin.url # timeout=10 06:08:18   > git submodule init #
> timeout=10 06:08:18   > git config -f .gitmodules --get-regexp
> ^submodule.(.+).url # timeout=10 06:08:18   > git config --get 
> timeout=10 06:08:18   > git remote # timeout=10 06:08:18   > git config --get remote.origin.url # timeout=10 06:08:18   > git config -f
> .gitmodules --get  # timeout=10 06:08:18   > git config --get
>  # timeout=10 06:08:18   > git remote # timeout=10 06:08:18   >
> git config --get remote.origin.url # timeout=10 06:08:18   > git
> config -f .gitmodules --get  # timeout=10 06:08:18   > git config
> --get submodule.code-insights.url # timeout=10 06:08:18   > git remote  timeout=10 06:08:18   > git config --get remote.origin.url # timeout=10 06:08:18   > git config -f .gitmodules --get 
> timeout=10 06:08:18   > git config --get
> submodule. # timeout=10 06:08:18   > git remote
> timeout=10 06:08:18   > git config --get remote.origin.url # timeout=10 06:08:18   > git config -f .gitmodules --get
> submodule. # timeout=10 06:08:18  using GIT_SSH
> to set credentials  06:08:18   > git submodule update --init
> --recursive  # timeout=30 06:08:18  using GIT_SSH to set credentials  06:08:18   > git submodule update --init
> --recursive  # timeout=30 06:08:18  using GIT_SSH to set credentials  06:08:18   > git submodule update --init
> --recursive  # timeout=30 06:08:19  using GIT_SSH to set credentials  06:08:19   > git submodule update --init
> --recursive  # timeout=30 06:08:19   > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10 06:08:19   > git config remote.origin.url  # timeout=10 06:08:19   > git rev-parse
> --verify HEAD # timeout=10

I wonder why the original developers did not include a "silent" switch.
If no solution exists, does someone suggest a plugin edit?

caution: i m not talking for SCM in general, rather than GitSCM itself.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try the suggested answers in the question you linked to?

Comment: Can you add more information about specifically which part of your build has too much output? Is it the pull? The checkout? Both?

Comment: The actual answer does not cover a groovy way of doing this, does not apply to GitSCM.
Attaching sample output (url names hidden)

Comment: Is GitSCM a plugin for Jenkins? A class lib for Groovy? Are you using Groovy for a scripting language? This is pretty important to note.

Comment: Can you add info about how the Jenkins pipeline is configured?